# MySQL uses 100% CPU - Not sure to configure

Tags: mysql

I'm running a VPS on DigitalOcean on a 8GB ram 4 Core.  We're on Ubuntu 32 bit.

Recently been running into the issue where the mysql process is taking up 100% of the CPU load and slowing our server.  I've tried all sorts of things from what I could find online, and would love some help in configuring our settings.

It is a database intensive site, we use it as an API endpoint for our main site and to host numerous others.

After running myqsltuner:

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log
[!!] Switch to 64-bit OS - MySQL cannot currently use all of your RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 312M (Tables: 84)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 7K (Tables: 23)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 84

-------- Security Recommendations  ------------------------------------    -------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 5m 44s (6K q [19.360 qps], 500 conn, TX: 4M, RX: 981K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 67% / 33%
[--] Total buffers: 1.7G global + 2.7M per thread (160 max threads)
[!!] Allocating > 2GB RAM on 32-bit systems can cause system instability
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.1G (26% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/6K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 5% (8/160)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/169.0K
[!!] Key buffer hit rate: 50.0% (6 cached / 3 reads)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 8.4% (355 cached / 4K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (2 temp sorts / 104 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 19% (54 on disk / 274 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (8 created / 500 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 95% (153 open / 160 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 9% (95/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (5K immediate / 5K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 312.9M/1.0G

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_limit (> 512M, or use smaller result sets)
```

[CPU Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iBR7.png)
Those spike ups are when a cron job seems to be running.  We have some that run analytics on our product data and update the corresponding tables with the results.

When it drops back down to 0, it's because I'm restarting the service after attempting to do some research, changing the settings, and restarting the service.

Comment: The first obvious thing to fix is running a 32-bit OS. You should _never_ do this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to get yourselves moved to a 64bit OS. This will allow you to use more of your system resources. Until you do that there is little point in doing anything else. Fiddling whilst Rome burns springs to mind.

Comment: While you are right in general - this definitly will not cause 100% CPU use.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code, not an admin issue.

Bear with me - I am a SQL Server guy, not MySql, but having seen this both in SQL Server and Oracle and understanding the reasons, I do not think that MySql is magically different.

I have yet to see a SQL Server CPU overloaded. No joke.

Generally, databases are not CPU bound but IO bound. IO often is mitigated with Memory (for caching).

But high (extremely high) CPU use is either a COMICAL bad server (like a qauad core for 2000 parallel requests), or a case of VERY badly written SQL (converting integers to strings, then joining them, for example).

Now, running a 32 bit system (bad mistake) will make sure you can not use really a halfway decent hardware (due to the 32 bit limitations on address space), but that MOSTLY should show in even less performance and CPU usage, as the CPU Waits for IO thanks to not enough buffering.

Now, if you count CPU LOAD not as utilization but as the Load factor - that would show as a high load factor, but not being a high utilization. CPU LOAD is shown as CPU processes waiting to bee processed, and the wait can be for an IO operation. This warrants further investigation, but it would not be as your title indicates: "MySQL uses 100% CPU" - which indicates CPU utilization, not a Load factor. And that really would point to ridiculously written SQL, missing indices on top.

If it is this - really look at the SQL. If it is a load factor, then go to a decent OS (which means 64 bit) and add RAM and check IO stats - there is a reason any decent database server since some time runs on SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Just share my experience, I've setup a LAMP stack 32bit linux VPS (ESXi) with 8G RAM running kernel-PAE, when website rollout and loading increase a little bit, php fastcgi and mysqld become high load, loadavg pump up to 100 and server become inaccessible.

And then I tried to switch the kernel back to normal 32bit, use ~4G RAM only, problem gone, but sometimes suffer from OOM-killer. So, I setup another 64bit server with same configuration and packages, switch everything into it. Up to now, almost 3 years without any problem.